# MYSQL value doesn't match input

Tags: php, mysql

I am a programmer and I have created a simple game that works with credits. Everything works fine now thanks to some help of this community.

Only one thing I can't get working properly. Let me explain. People can donate to contribute to my project. When they click on a set of four buttons a value shows in a input text box. I use the following code:

```html
<button value="0.10" class="round-button">&#8364; 0.10</button>
<button value="0.25" class="round-button">&#8364; 0.25</button>
<button value="0.50" class="round-button">&#8364; 0.50</button>
<button value="1.00" class="round-button">&#8364; 1.00</button>

<form action="validate.php" method="post">
<input name="total" type="text" class="total" id="total" />
<input type="image" src="image/accept.fw.png" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This not all to difficult. But next I post this to my file called validate.php. Everything works also fine here, this is my validate.php

```html
include 'sql.php';
$query_pretest = mysql_query("SELECT credits FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['login']."'");
$check = mysql_fetch_array($query_pretest);

$total = $_POST['total']; 
if ($check['credits']<=($_POST['total'])) { echo 'not enough money in your account'; }
else { mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credits = (credits -'{$_POST[total]}') WHERE username='".$_SESSION['login']."'"); echo 'Thanks for your donation'; }
```

Ok, so this works, but now something strange happens. When a user selects for example 0.85 cents and he has 5.00 in his account, than the user has after the donation 4.00 left. It looks like the value 0.85 is transfered to 1.0?

What am I doing wrong or do I need something else in the database?
My column in the database called Credits has a 'int(11)', so perhaps I need to set it up diffrent? Does anyone could give me a direction?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `int` datatype can only store whole numbers, not fractions.

Comment: Convert your integer (`int`) column type to a (`float`) and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INTEGER` types can only store whole numbers, not fractions. There are two common ways to store monetary values in a database:

1. Use `DECIMAL(11,2)` instead of `INT(11)` as the datatype. This specifies a value with 11 total digits, including 2 digits after the decimal point.
2. Use `INT(11)`, and store the number of cents rather than euros, by multiplying everything by `100`. Do this in the HTML as well, e.g.

   ```
   <button value="10" class="round-button">&#8364; 0.10</button>
   ```

I don't recommend using `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, because this can introduce floating point errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `int` to `double` in you're database.

Comment: True, I solved this by the next lines before adding data to de DB

$round = number_format((float)$_POST['totaal'], 2, '.', ''); and 
my query looks now like this: UPDATE users SET credits = (credits -'$round') WHERE username='".$_SESSION['login']."'");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, It did the trick. I am now going to study more about the use of a MySQL database. Stupid me...